# Same name for Header file and Source File

Tags: c, file, header

what is the intention for source file and header file to be same name in embedded programming?

Is it like we can declare functions in header file and then define them in source file.

Example.h has function declarations

```
void func();
```

Example.c has function definition

```
void func()
{
 printf("Do Nothing");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "same name"? Do you mean the actual files or do you mean the symbols inside the files? And yes, header files are commonly used for declarations of function while their definitions is in a separate source file. It's one of the purposes of header files, to declare things, so you can include it in multiple source files and have the same declaration everywhere the header file is included.

Comment: Do you mean the same name *except* for the `.h` and `.c` extensions?  That is not mandatory, but it is a very good idea.  It means that you can easily associate the header file as being the declarations of the non-static items in a file of source code.  It is not specific to embedded programming.

Comment: The "file name extension" (.c, .h, .bla, ...) ***is** part* of the file name.

Answer (score 3):

It's largely a matter of taste.  I find it is convenient when writing libraries to give the main .c file the name of the library, and the .h file that users will #include obviously takes that name to make things easy for users.

In a non-library source base, some people like having a .h file for every .c file that declares all the externs in that .c file.  Personally, I dislike this--it requires every file that uses these externs to know the file they reside in, and it makes splitting large files tedious, as you need to update the .h file and all the .c files that #include it.  I prefer having .h files that cover an area of the code, not a specific file; in smallish codebases where modularity isn't an issue, a single externs.h file for everything works well in my opinion.  But this is definitely a matter of taste on which capable engineers can disagree.

(But note that declaring all externs in a .h file, and having the .c file that instantiates that global #include that .h file, is fundamental to good coding.  No extern keyword should ever appear in a .c file, and you should light the compiler warning flag to error on globals definitions without a matching extern declaration; that guarantees that every file agrees on what the extern symbol is declared as)